# Java Custom Data Type

Tags: java, object, custom-data-type

I wanted to create a class with a custom data type that returns the class object. Consider a class Custom:

```
public class Custom {
    // Some fields.
    public Custom(String custom) {
        // Some Text.
    }
    // Some Methods.
    public void customMethod() {
        // Some Code.
    }
}
```

Now, consider a second class TestCustom:

```
public class TestCustom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Custom custom = new Custom("Custom");
        System.out.println(custom); // This should print "Custom"
        custom.customMethod(); // This should perform the action
    }
}
```

So, the question how to get the value custom on instantiating an object instead of memory location. Like what I get is:

```
Custom@279f2327
```

Comment: *"java constructors don't return a value"* they don't? Then how are you able to assign an created instance to a variable?

Comment: @Tom constructors don't return a value: instance creation expressions do (for which part of the evaluation is to invoke the constructor).

Comment: @MansoorAhmedNemon And while we're at it: don't ever use `Date` or `Calendar`. Those are obsolete classes; use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `toString()` method, as it is automatically invoked when you try to display an object:

Add a field. For example;

```
private String value;
```

In the constructor, add the following code:

```
value = custom;
```

this will assign a value passed to the constructor as a parameter, to the `value` field.

And finally override the toString() method as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
}
```

Now, when you display the value of the custom object, the overridden `toString()` method will be invoked and the argument will be displayed instead of the memory address. Whereas methods of the object will work as they are programmed to work. There is nothing to be changed with them.

Answer (score 2):

The java.util.Date class returns the current date. This can be seen as the constructor for the class is

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

For example, the following code would print out the current date:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: Correct Answer, addressing the Question. But I’ll note that these terrible legacy classes should no longer be used. JSR 310 replaced them with the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by ML72](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650178/642706) is correct and should be accepted. The `java.util.Date` constructor captures the current moment in UTC.

## java.time

The `java.util.Date` class is *terrible*, for many reasons. That class is now legacy, supplanted years ago but the *java.time* classes as of the adoption of JSR 310.

The *java.time* classes avoid constructors, instead using factory methods.

The replacement for `java.util.Date` is `java.time.Instant`. To capture the current moment in UTC, call the class method `.now()`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

If you want the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), use `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Notice again the factory method rather than a constructor.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```